# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list (Function)

Tags: python

```
variableName=["display","screen","sound""audio"]
fileName=["PPP", "Abc"]
P1="PPP"
d="display"
s="screen"
ss="sound"
a="audio"
d=P1
loop=True
def CH(variableName, fileName, loop):
    while loop==True:
        Up=input("What is your problem?\n")
        if (variableName) in Up.lower():
            file = open(fileName + ".txt", "r")
            whole= file.read()
            print(whole)
            file.close()
            loop=False
        else:
            loop=True
            continue**

CH(variableName, fileName, loop)
```

I am trying to create a function that read your input and give an answer by using keywords. But the error ""TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list"" keeps coming up and I can seem to fix it

Comment: What do you expect `if (variableName) in Up.lower():` to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got the logic of your `in` statement backwards. You should be checking

```
if Up.lower() in variableName:
```

not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

If variableName is a list, you can check membership with `.__contains__()`.

Try changing the if statement to `if variableName.__contains__(Up.lower):`

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
if (variableName) in Up.lower():
```

....tests for the existence of a `tuple` `(variableName)` in a string `Up.lower()`.

Since `variableName` is actually a list of strings, depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may well want to use one of the following instead:

```
if any(s in Up.lower() for s in variableName):

if all(s in Up.lower() for s in variableName):
```

- The `any()` option will return `True` if `any` of the strings `s` in `variableName` are in `Up.lower()`.
- The `all` option will return `True` if `all` of the strings `s` in `variableName` are in `Up.lower()`.